# Deriving a welfare function

Tags: social-welfare, endogenous-growth

I saw this in a paper (however, I cannot derive it):
We define the growth rate of consumption as $g_{C, s} \equiv \frac{C_s}{C_{s-1}}$ and use $C_t=\left(\prod_{s=1}^t g_{C, s}\right) C_0$ to rewrite lifetime utility, $\mathcal{V}_0=$ $\mathbb{E}_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left(C_t\right)$, as
$$
\mathcal{V}_0=\frac{1}{1-\beta}\left[\log \left(C_0\right)+\mathbb{E}_0\left(\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left(g_{C, t}\right)\right)\right]
$$

My attempt:

$$
 \mathcal{V}_0= \mathbb{E}_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left(C_t\right) =\mathbb{E}_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left( \left(\prod_{s=1}^t g_{C, s}\right) C_0 \right)
 $$
$$
 \mathcal{V}_0 = \mathbb{E}_0 \Big[
\frac{1}{1-\beta } \log C_0 +  \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \log \left(\prod_{s=1}^t g_{C, s}\right)
 \Big]
 $$
$$
 \mathcal{V}_0 = \mathbb{E}_0 \Big[
\frac{1}{1-\beta } \log C_0 +  \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \left(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\right)
 \Big]
 $$
$$
 \mathcal{V}_0 = \Big[
\frac{1}{1-\beta } \log C_0 +   \mathbb{E}_0 \left( \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \Big(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\Big) \right)
 \Big]
 $$

Why is $\mathbb{E}_0 \left( \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \Big(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\Big) \right)= \frac{1}{1-\beta }  \mathbb{E}_0 \Big( \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t  \log g_{C, t} \Big)$?